# Нажатие кнопки в WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо нажать кнопку в *WebBrowser*. Код кнопки в HTML:

```
<a class="-cx-PRIVATE-Info__OneButton -cx-PRIVATE-OneButton__root 
        -cx-PRIVATE-Util__hideText coreOneButton" href="#" role="button">
    Button one
</a>
```

А вот код, с помощью которого я пытаюсь нажать на эту кнопку:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement elem in elc)
{
    if (elem.GetAttribute("class").Equals("-cx-PRIVATE-Info__OneButton -cx-PRIVATE-OneButton__root" +  
            "-cx-PRIVATE-Util__hideText coreOneButton"))
    {
        elem.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Но нажатие не происходит. Через атрибут `role` тоже не получилось, но с `role` проблема ещё в том, что такой атрибут стоит и на других кнопках.

И ещё вопрос: можно ли искать элемент по тексту внутри него (`<a>Some text</a>`)?

Comment: Вы проверяли коллекцию `elc` вообще на наличие в ней элементов? Быть может, вы вызывает этот код до того, как будет закончено формирование `document`-a, и поэтому коллекция пуста?

Comment: @Regent        Да, проверял(25 элементов). Код вызываю после полной загрузки документа (Код вызывается кнопкой, в которой состояние `Enable= true` присваивается  по событию `DocumentCompleted`). Может быть нельзя искать по атрибуту `а`?

Comment: Отчего же нельзя? `<a>` - вполне себе `HTMLElement`, и атрибуты у него никто не отменял. Вы пробовали внутри цикла писать `Console.WriteLine(elem.GetAttribute("class"));`?

Comment: В консоль выводит пустые строки. В режиме отладки просмотрел все 25 элементов, и там есть этот элемент (Искал по параметру `OuterHtml` и `OuterText`), через атрибут `role` все находит и нажимает(проблема была в `Button`, а нужно было `button`), но нажимает на первую попавшуюся кнопку, а не на ту что мне нужно.

Comment: Попробуйте, кстати, `"className"` вместо `"class"`.

Comment: @Regent        Большое спасибо за советы. `className` действительно  выдает нужный результат.

Comment: На здоровье. Думаю, имеет смысл сделать через него, потому что`.Contains()` для `outerHTML` - уж больно нестабильный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Решил так:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement elem in elc)
{
    if (elem.GetAttribute("className").Contains("coreOneButton"))
    {
        elem.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Спасибо **Regent** и **Qwertiy** за наводку.

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, ты сравниваешь значение атрибута, так что надо быть очень осторожным со всякими переводами строк и множественными пробелами. Возможно, есть ещё что-то.

Правильнее было бы использовать `GetElementsByClassName` указав нужное имя класса (но только одно).

А ещё правильнее - не использовать `WebBrowser`.